# Service instance parameters update in CF user provided service

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud

I am new to Cloud Foundry and I have deployed local bosh-lite CF installation.

I have a Spring Boot with Hibernate JPA application which connects to postgresql which is again running locally which i want to deploy.

For this i created an user provided service for postgresql with service instance parameters of host,port,username and password.

Now i deployed the app and have bound the app to the service instance.

Now when i restart the app the app fails with some connection error (host name was wrong) to the db instance. 
I changed the service instance parameters using cfups command to update the host parameters. The command returned 0 as response.

Now i restage the application to let the changes take effect. But the app again fails with the same error pointing to the old host parameter.

It seems  either the parameter changes did not take place using the cfups command or somehow the app is not getting restaged with the new parameters.

Another question how do i get to see the current service instance parameters of the already running service instance. ? cf service servicename only gives the name and the apps bound to it

**UPDATE**

I followed the tutorial here  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3DbtW5lwqY by Scott Frederick and went with the third option i.e. to configure by having spring boot cloud connector and postgresql driver in my classpath.

So in bullett points my scenario

- Deployed bosh-lite in Vagrant based Virtual Box Ubuntu
- Installed Postgresql on host machine
- Deployed my Spring Boot application configured with Spring boot cloud connector
- Created a Postgresql CF service instance
- Bound my application with the service instance
- App cannot start and fails with connection refused error.
- I checked the postgres instance in my local machine. On curl localhost:5432 it is running empty response that means it is working. I am even login using psql

Below is the output of my cf env app` . Host of service instance parameter "postgressql-service-instance1" is the ip of my host machine which has the postgresql isntalled. I am on a Vagrant based Virtual Box Ubuntu.

```
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "user-provided": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "host": "10.0.2.2",
     "password": "admin",
     "port": "5432",
     "username": "postgres"
    },
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "postgresql-service-instance1",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "application_id": "194af4c6-5bbc-4644-af04-55cdaff12b6d",
  "application_name": "employeerest2",
  "application_uris": [
   "employeerest2.bosh-lite.com"
  ],
  "application_version": "facfce7e-9436-4059-94e8-3139172fa482",
  "cf_api": "https://api.bosh-lite.com",
  "limits": {
   "disk": 1024,
   "fds": 16384,
   "mem": 256
  },
  "name": "employeerest2",
  "space_id": "9a8b306d-8509-4241-b1fc-3ecb652c0733",
  "space_name": "development",
  "uris": [
   "employeerest2.bosh-lite.com"
  ],
  "users": null,
  "version": "facfce7e-9436-4059-94e8-3139172fa482"
 }
}

No user-defined env variables have been set

No running env variables have been set

No staging env variables have been set
```

As you can see my app is bound to an service. But whenver i try to restart, restage the app i get the following error` Which clearly shows the connection is refused at localhost:5432. But i am not using localhost as a host service parameter to connect to.

I have configured my postgresql instance to accept connection from my guest OS. I don't know how Spring Boot is getting the host name as "localhost"

```
2017-06-01T21:51:55.74+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT     ... 53 common frames omitted
2017-06-01T21:51:55.75+0530 [App/0] OUT 2017-06-01 16:21:55.751 ERROR 29 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2017-06-01T21:51:55.76+0530 [App/0] OUT 2017-06-01 16:21:55.760  WARN 29 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-06-01T21:51:55.76+0530 [App/0] OUT 2017-06-01 16:21:55.765  INFO 29 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2017-06-01T21:51:55.78+0530 [App/0] OUT 2017-06-01 16:21:55.789  INFO 29 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 
2017-06-01T21:51:55.78+0530 [App/0] OUT Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT 2017-06-01 16:21:55.794 ERROR 29 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.3.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.saurav.cf.casestudy.employee.EmployeerestApplication.main(EmployeerestApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [app/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [app/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [app/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [app/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     ... 24 common frames omitted
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ExtractionContextImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     ... 30 common frames omitted
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar!/:na]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ExtractionContextImpl.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     ... 37 common frames omitted
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.79+0530 [App/0] OUT     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.80+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.80+0530 [App/0] OUT     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar!/:9.4.1212.jre7]
2017-06-01T21:51:55.80+0530 [App/0] OUT     ... 53 common frames omitted
2017-06-01T21:51:55.81+0530 [App/0] ERR
```

Saurav

Comment: Try unbinding the user-provided service from the app, re-binding it, then restaging the app.

Comment: Did that already ...but it did not help

Comment: Run `cf env <app>` and look at the VCAP_SERVICES env variable.  That should show you what's currently bound to the app.  You can run `cf curl /v2/user_provided_service_instances/$(cf service <service-name> --guid)` to see the details of the user provided service.

Comment: @DanielMikusa..thanks a ton..this was i looking for..i can see the parameter updated for the service instance but don't know why the app is not using the latest parameters...

Comment: How are you expecting the app to get the host and other values from the ups? Are you using `spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors`, or setting Boot properties directly from `vcap.services...` properties, or doing something else?

Comment: `cf env <app>` will show you the parameters last set.
`cf ssh <app> -c printenv` will show you the parameters actually set in app container (look for `VCAP_SERVICES`). These will only be updated after the restage/restart. If this displays what you expected, the issue is that your app/Spring is not reading them in. See Scott's comment on that.

Comment: @ScottFrederick sorry for coming back late as i was trying out few things ...i followed your talk ..i am trying to configure through spring boot cloud connector...i have updated my post above with some more details

Answer (score 0):

ok...finally i was able to tie all loose threads on this topic.

Just to summarize the overall solution for other readers. For some more details you can visit here [No unique service maching interface error in Spring Boot Cloud Foundry error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418856/no-unique-service-maching-interface-error-in-spring-boot-cloud-foundry-error)

If you have a scenario where you want to have a spring boot application talk to a database (hosted in other machine) and then run the application from cloud foundry. Then follow some of the tips below.

1. Once you deploy your Spring Boot application and want to use Spring Boot cloud connector make sure you have all the proper dependencies in your classpath (spring-boot-cloud-connector and jar.
   If you want to bind a service instance with the application .
2. Make sure the credentials adhere to this specification http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_postgresql
3. In the service instance parameters make sure you use the uri parameter not depend on the username and password to construct the uri
4. Make sure your database instance is actually running and you have created application service groups to allow outbound communication from your cloud foundry app. https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/asg.html#viewing

Steps 3 and 4 were the mistakes i made. Once corrected the application works fine.

Best Regards, Saurav